Censored anime or mangas or 3d cartoons
I am a 18 year old boy from Asia. I have been brought up as a Muslim since I was a child and I try to stay halal and follow Allah's path. I was wondering if watching censored hentai is haram. Since it is censored I cannot see the genitals of either the male or the female. At best I can see the female's chest but that is as far as I can see. So, if I cannot see the genitals of either the characters, is it haram to watch?

Use relevant tags. What is the point of watching it other than to arouse sexual desire and hence tempt yourself to do something haram.
